# Run 2 slurm jobs only when both get the allocated resources

Tags: pytorch, scheduled-tasks, distributed-computing, slurm

One job is submitted to get hold of 4 GPUs. The second is submitted to get hold of the next 4 GPUs (on a different node). How can I ensure that both of the jobs run at the same time such that they eventually synchronise (Pytorch DPP).

Having an extra script to check the available resources does the trick, however other jobs might have priority because they have been in the queue, rather than waiting...

The particular partition I am using does not allow for a request of 2 nodes directly.

I am also aware of the `--dependency` flag, however this can only be used as a completion check of the first job.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to be more explicit with slurm.

```
idx=0; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=1 &
idx=1; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=2 &
idx=1; export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$idx; python -u run_pos.py --fold=3 &

wait
```

**srun examples**

Jobs will be allocated specific generic resources as needed to satisfy the request. If the job is suspended, those resources do not become available for use by other jobs.

Job steps can be allocated generic resources from those allocated to the job using the --gres option with the srun command as described above. By default, a job step will be allocated all of the generic resources allocated to the job. If desired, the job step may explicitly specify a different generic resource count than the job. This design choice was based upon a scenario where each job executes many job steps. If job steps were granted access to all generic resources by default, some job steps would need to explicitly specify zero generic resource counts, which we considered more confusing. The job step can be allocated specific generic resources and those resources will not be available to other job steps. A simple example is shown below.

***Flags explained***

1. **--gres** - Generic resources required per node
2. **--gpus** - GPUs required per job
3. **--gpus-per-node** - GPUs required per node. Equivalent to the --gres option for GPUs.
4. **--gpus-per-socket** - GPUs required per socket. Requires the job to specify a task socket.
5. **--gpus-per-task** - GPUs required per task. Requires the job to specify a task count.
6. **--cpus-per-gpu** - Count of CPUs allocated per GPU.
7. **--gpu-bind** - Define how tasks are bound to GPUs.
8. **--gpu-freq** - Specify GPU frequency and/or GPU memory frequency.
9. **--mem-per-gpu** - Memory allocated per GPU.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# gres_test.bash
# Submit as follows:
# sbatch --gres=gpu:4 -n4 -N1-1 gres_test.bash
#
srun --gres=gpu:2 -n2 --exclusive show_device.sh &
srun --gres=gpu:1 -n1 --exclusive show_device.sh &
srun --gres=gpu:1 -n1 --exclusive show_device.sh &
wait
```

Another example:

```
srun --gres=gpu:1 bash -c 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$SLURM_PROCID env' | grep CUDA_VISIBLE

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
```

You can further automate this with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --qos=maxjobs
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --exclusive


for i in `seq 0 3`; do
    cd ${i}
    export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$i
    python gpu_code.py &
    cd ..
done
wait
```

The complex but better answer...

The Multi-Process Service MPS is an implementation variant compatible with the CUDA programming interface. The MPS execution architecture is designed to let co-operative multi-process CUDA applications, generally for MPI jobs, use Hyper-Q functionalities on the very latest NVIDIA GPUs. Hyper-Q allows CUDA kernels to be processed simultaneously on the same GPU; this can improve performance when the GPU calculation capacity is underused by a single application process.

CUDA MPS is included by default in the different CUDA modules available to the users.

For a multi-GPU MPI batch job, the usage of `CUDA MPS` can be activated with the `-C mps` option. However, the node must be exclusively reserved via the `--exclusive` option.

For an execution via the default gpu partition (nodes with 40 physical cores and 4 GPUs) using only one node:

**mps_multi_gpu_mpi.slurm**

```
#!/bin/bash

SBATCH --job-name=gpu_cuda_mps_multi_mpi # name of job
SBATCH --ntasks=40  # total number of MPI tasks
SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40  # number of MPI tasks per node (all physical cores)
SBATCH --gres=gpu:4  # number of GPUs per node (all GPUs)
SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1  # number of cores per task 

# /!\ Caution: In Slurm vocabulary, "multithread" refers to hyperthreading.

SBATCH --hint=nomultithread  # hyperthreading deactivated
SBATCH --time=00:10:00  # maximum execution time requested (HH:MM:SS)
SBATCH --output=gpu_cuda_mps_multi_mpi%j.out # name of output file
SBATCH --error=gpu_cuda_mps_multi_mpi%j.out  # name of error file (here, common with the output)

SBATCH --exclusive   # exclusively reserves the node 
SBATCH -C mps    # the MPS is activated  
         
# cleans out modules loaded in interactive and inherited by default
module purge
         
# loads modules
module load ...
         
# echo of launched commands
set -x
         
# execution of the code with binding via bind_gpu.sh: 4 GPUs for 40 MPI tasks.
srun ./executable_multi_gpu_mpi
```

**Submit script via the sbatch command:**

**sbatch mps_multi_gpu_mpi.slurm**
Similarly, you can execute your job on an entire node of the gpu_p2 partition (nodes with 24 physical cores and 8 GPUs) by specifying:

```
SBATCH --partition=gpu_p2 ​           # GPU partition requested 
SBATCH --ntasks=24 ​                  # total number of MPI tasks 
SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=24 ​         # number of MPI tasks per node (all physical cores)
SBATCH --gres=gpu:8                  # number of GPUs per node (all GPUs)
SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1 ​            # number of cores per task
```

Be careful, even if you use only part of the node, it has to be reserved in exclusive mode. In particular, this means that the entire node is invoiced.
I recommend that you compile and execute your codes in the same environment by loading the same modules. In this example, I assume that the `executable_mps_multi_gpu_mpi` executable file is found in the submission directory, i.e. the directory in which the sbatch command is entered.

The calculation output file, gpu_cuda_mps_multi_mpi<numero_job>.out, is also found in the submission directory. It is created at the start of the job execution: Editing or modifying it while the job is running can disrupt the execution.

The module purge is made necessary by the Slurm default behaviour: Any modules which are loaded in your environment at the moment when you launch `sbatch` will be passed to the submitted job making the execution of your job dependent on what you have done previously.

**PROTIP:** To avoid errors in the automatic task distribution, I recommend using `srun` to execute your code instead of `mpirun`. This guarantees a distribution which conforms to the specifications of the resources you requested in the submission file.

**Misc.**
Jobs have resources defined in Slurm by default, per partition and per QoS (Quality of Service). You can modify the limits or specify another partition and / or QoS as shown in the documentation detailing the partitions and QoS.

That was exhaustive, I HOPE THAT HELPS!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. This does not guarantee that resources are granted at the same time.

Comment: This uncalled-for response does not mitigate that your tutorial does not answer the question. And how would you even arrive at "literally hundreds"?

Comment: Because 2 ppl have marked it correct and the person that posted the question got their problem solved.